# bad substitution in a bash script

Tags: bash

I've inherited a bash script (aren't legacies wonderful!) and I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong.

The offending line is this:
     `while [ "${\(\#\)}" -gt 0 ] ; do`

and I get a "bad substitution" error message when I try to run it.  I'm pretty sure it's trying to ask if the number of args is greater than zero, but you know that too.

I don't know if it ever worked.  I imagine there are not enough backslashes, or maybe too many, or maybe the parentheses don't belong there.  I tried several of these, but no luck.

Any enlightenment appreciated.

Comment: I overlooked the bit about "not enough backslashes" when I answered.  Are there some backslashes in the script near the `while` line?  If a script is writing a script into another file, it could use \$# to delay evaluation of $#.

Comment: when dealing with legacy code like this always assume that it worked at some point. I would check you input params for validity.

Answer (score 2):

Although the original line produces the error message you mentioned (Bad substitution), just removing the parentheses should be enough to fix the problem.  For example, with the following in file `while-num`

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ "${#}" -gt 0 ] ; do
    echo $1
    shift
done
```

and invoked with (eg)
`./while-num 18173.msg 18179.msg 18201.msg` produces

```
18173.msg
18179.msg
18201.msg
```

On my Ubuntu-12 system, the same output results when the first line is `#!/bin/sh`.  (On Ubuntu the default shell is dash instead of bash.) It also works fine when the `while` line is changed to `while[ $# -gt 0 ] ; do` (ie the quotes and braces are not needed because `$#` returns a number).

Comment: Yeah, the backslashes were eaten, alas.  

The actual code looked like this, where b means backslash:
    
while [ "${b(b#b)}" -gt 0 ] ; do

I'm not sure what they backslashes were supposed to achieve.

Comment: @user1674956, you probably can edit the post and put the \'s back in; surround the `\(` by one code-formatting backtick on each side  ``.  Without the whole context I can't say what was going on.